# postgresql 10 altering serial column error 42p01

Tags: postgresql

I am facing an issue when correcting an existing table to use serial column on the primary key. In order to simulate the issue I created a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE markets."TestSequence" (
    "Id" integer NOT NULL,
    "Name" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT "PK_TestSequence" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
);
```

Then I ran the query that is causing problem:

```
ALTER TABLE markets."TestSequence" ALTER COLUMN "Id" TYPE integer;
ALTER TABLE markets."TestSequence" ALTER COLUMN "Id" SET NOT NULL;
CREATE SEQUENCE "TestSequence_Id_seq" AS integer START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NO MINVALUE NO MAXVALUE NO CYCLE;
ALTER TABLE markets."TestSequence" ALTER COLUMN "Id" SET DEFAULT (nextval('"TestSequence_Id_seq"'));
ALTER SEQUENCE "TestSequence_Id_seq" OWNED BY "TestSequence"."Id";
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  relation "TestSequence" does not exist
SQL state: 42P01
```

According to the [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-altersequence.html) `OWNED BY` does not take any schema prefix. So I tried to create the table without schema and it works fine.

```
CREATE TABLE "TestSequence" (
    "Id" integer NOT NULL,
    "Name" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT "PK_TestSequence" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
);
```

and run the corresponding alter queries:

```
ALTER TABLE "TestSequence" ALTER COLUMN "Id" TYPE integer;
ALTER TABLE "TestSequence" ALTER COLUMN "Id" SET NOT NULL;
CREATE SEQUENCE "TestSequence_Id_seq" AS integer START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NO MINVALUE NO MAXVALUE NO CYCLE;
ALTER TABLE "TestSequence" ALTER COLUMN "Id" SET DEFAULT (nextval('"TestSequence_Id_seq"'));
ALTER SEQUENCE "TestSequence_Id_seq" OWNED BY "TestSequence"."Id";
```

How can I make this work for relations with schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altersequence.html) you have linked says, for `owned by`

> The specified table must have the same owner and be in the same schema
> as the sequence.

You haven't specified a schema for the sequence, so it is created in `public` by default, which is not the same as the table schema.

Try creating the sequence as

```
CREATE SEQUENCE markets."TestSequence_Id_seq" AS integer  ...
```

That being said, nothing prevents you from specifying the schema of both the sequence and the table

```
ALTER SEQUENCE markets."TestSequence_Id_seq" OWNED BY markets."TestSequence"."Id";
```

Comment: I added the schema on create sequence, nextval(), and alter sequence but I get the same error.

Comment: @herme0 see edits, you can specify the schema for both the table and the sequence

Comment: it did the job, tnx